# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int64 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm getting the following error in my MVC2 app using Linq to SQL (I am new to both). I am connected to an actual SQL server not weird mdf:

```
System.InvalidOperationException The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int64 which is a non-nullable value type
```

My SQL table has a column called MessageID. It is BigInt type and has a primary key, NOT NULL and an IDENTITY 1 1, no Default

In my dbml designer it has the following declaration for this field:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_MessageId", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public long MessageId
{
    get
    {
        return this._MessageId;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._MessageId != value))
        {
            this.OnMessageIdChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._MessageId = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("MessageId");
            this.OnMessageIdChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps telling me that null cannot be assigned - I'm not passing through null! It's a long - it can't even be null!

Am I doing something stupid? I can't find a solution anywhere!

I made this work by changing the type of this property to `Nullable<long>` but surely this can't be right?

**Update:**
I am using InsertOnSubmit. Simplified code:

```
public ActionResult Create(Message message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var db = new MessagingDataContext();
       db.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(message);
       db.SubmitChanges(); //line 93 (where it breaks)
    }
}
```

breaks on SubmitChanges() with the error at the top of this question.

**Update2:**
Stack trace:

```
   at Read_Object(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at Qanda.Controllers.MessagingController.Ask(Message message) in C:\Qanda\Qanda\Controllers\MessagingController.cs:line 93
```

**Update3:**
No one knows and I don't have enough clout to offer a bounty! So continued on my [ASP.NET blog](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/04/linq-to-sql-null-value-cannot-be.html). Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to use InsertOnSubmit method and does it result in this exception?

Comment: can you show the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Can you give us a stack trace?

Comment: i have updated with the stacktrace

Comment: Can you post the contents of your message object? Have you tried running a profiler against the database during your call to db.SubmitChanges()?

Comment: Where do you create the `Message` object you are passing to your `Create` method and how?

Comment: I've had this problem before... do you have any associations in the dbml that use message id?

Comment: Check for any Unique key constrain in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has taken a while but I have discovered this was happening and thought I'd share. It was because the table had a trigger on insert. I've wrote about it in more detail here  [optimistic concurrency exception with triggers](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/entity-framework-optimisticconcurrencye.html). Although this is with entity framework, I'm still sure it is the trigger causing  my dismay from the start

Comment: +1 Thanks for blogging this.  It was the only reference I could find after wasting an two hours of pointless debugging.  I'm back to ADO.Net for this one.

Comment: +1 for me too, except mine is System.Int32 (identity column data type is INT); also had an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. The underlying problem is that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `NULL` when the trigger is active (seems like a bug to me); the older not-recommended `@@IDENTITY` value is correct though.

Comment: BTW, this is a known issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/427640/instead-trigger-break-the-scope-identity-scope

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the correct direction. Deleting the trigger was not an option. Found that returning the identity value in OUTPUT inside of the trigger helped. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482025/using-output-into-within-instead-of-insert-trigger-invalidates-inserted-table) post guided me in the correct direction. I needed to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY back to the calling code to get the ID of the inserted row.

Answer (score 2):

The value types you have defined in your Result class need to be setup as nullable.

In your case use int64?

Check out the object code in your designer.cs file that was generated by the designer, if you are using it.

Modify this code and place it in a partial class so the designer will not over write the code.

Comment: or just set it in the dbml properties: nullable=false. okay, this works but why should it be nullable? i noticed this fixes it but wanted to make sure this is the right thing to do. not just a hack

Comment: Value types cannot be null,  database fields return null values, when they are passed they will throw an exception.  By setting the value type variable to nullable, value types can accept null values.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem calling a stored procedure returning data of 3 tables with Left outer join the problem was that a Column with Bigint Type was Null So I applied ISNULL(OID,0) in the procedure to overcome in LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Check first which column is cause of exception then set its default value in table or EF Model if you are using it.

If you save nothing for this column it will store with default value and this error will never occur again.